# Laravel 5.4 query by month

Tags: sql, laravel, graph, eloquent

I'm building a forum and now I want to show the message count for every user in a graph with `chart.js`.

In Laravel 5.4 I've got this query:

```
return DB::table('message')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as messages, extract(month from message.created_at) as month'))
            ->join('user', 'message.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
            ->where('user.id', $user->id)
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->get();
```

But this does not show `0` if there are no messages in a `month`.

So for example now I receive this:

```
[16, 38, 100]
```

But I need this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 16, 38, 100, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How could I get this result!?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show the full results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_fill_keys` to generate a list of empty months.

Then, use `array_replace` to fill in the months for which you do have data:

```php
$results = DB::table('message')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as messages, extract(month from message.created_at) as month')
    ->leftjoin('user', 'message.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
    ->where('user.id', $user->id)
    ->groupBy('month')
    ->pluck('messages', 'month');

return array_replace(array_fill_keys(range(1, 12), 0), $results->all());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got this now:

```
 public function UserMessages(User $user)
    {
        $months = collect([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

        $query = DB::table('message')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as messages, extract(month from message.created_at) as month'))
            ->leftjoin('user', 'message.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
            ->where('user.id', $user->id)
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->pluck('messages', 'month');

        return $months->map(function($value, $key) use ($query) {
            if(isset($query[$key +1], $query)) {
                return $query[$key +1];
            }

            return 0;
        })->toArray();
    }
```

But I guess there is a much cleaner way.

Answer (score -1):

because you are using `join`, instead of that use the `left join`

```
->leftJoin('user', 'message.user_id', '=', 'user.user_id')
```

[For Refernce](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins)

When you use a join in SQL it **only gets the data which matches**, so if you want all the data from the table referred first (or in left side) use the left join. For your clarification read about SQL joins. 
 
[SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Because it's the wrong answer (not my downvote). The join is between users and messages. There's no months table in the join, so a left join won't help.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But @JosephSilber is right. A left join won't help. Do I have to create a separate table with all months?

Comment: Ya that's my bad i just consider the results, and gave the bad answer. You don't need to create a table. You can have array of months and use it, months not going to change....@Jamie